# Laravel getting special languages posts with laravel-translatable

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the [laravel-translatable](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-translatable/v6/introduction) library for developing a multi-language web system. In this web application, there is no front-end, and the data is read and written through APIs. The problem I am facing is that I cannot fetch all the records stored in the database in one or more languages, for example, all records from the 'blog' table where the title is in English and French. The library documentation does not explicitly mention this, and I could not solve the issue with the codes I have tested. The following are the code examples I tried, but none of them resolved my problem:

```php
//1)
Route::get('/', function () {
    return response()->json(
        DB::table('blogs')
        ->get()
        ->filter(function ($blog) {
            return $blog->getTranslations('title', ['en']);
        })
    );
});

//2)
Route::get('/', function () {
    return response()->json(
        DB::table('blogs')
        ->get()
        ->filter(function ($blog) {
            return collect(json_decode($blog->title))->has('en');
        })
    );
});

//3)
Route::get('/', function () {
    return response()->json(Blog::titleEqualsEn()->get(), 200);
});
```

Server database type: `MariaDB`

blog migration:

```php
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->json('title');
        $table->json('content');
    });
}
```

Comment: when posting (saving) Blogs are you setting the translation? ->setTranslation('name', 'en', 'Name in English') ->setTranslation('name', 'nl', 'Naam in het Nederlands')  ->save();

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that library is setting different languages in JSON format, creating different keys for different languages. So presumably you could query for all blogs with an English title like:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return response()->json(
        Blog::whereNotNull('title->en')
        ->get()
    );
});
```

According to their documentation, if you're using MaraiDB 10.2.3 or above you'll need to use a raw version of the query such like

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        return response()->json(
            Blog::whereRaw("JSON_EXTRACT(title, '$.en') IS NOT NULL")
            ->get()
        );
    });
```

Comment: it didn't worked

Comment: @DolDurma Care to elaborate? Did it return zero record? Did you look into the database to check what data was actually stored in the `title` column?

Comment: @rager `whereRaw("JSON_EXTRACT(title, '$.en') IS NOT NULL")`  and `->whereNotNull('title->en')` return `title '{"en":"hello","fa":"\\u0645\\u062a\\u0646 \\u0641\\u0627\\u0631\\u0633\\u06cc"}'`

Comment: @DolDurma that's because of the query, it isn't aware of your models. I've updated my answer to initiate queries from the Models which should give you the proper response.

Comment: @Rager it didn't worked again :(

Comment: Yeah, I dunno, I built a test application with the library and it works for me.

Comment: @Rager can i share my code with you?